# Graphing with matplotlib: hours shown as float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting the frequency of something happening like so:

```
 graph=y.date.groupby(y.date.dt.hour).count().plot(kind='bar')
 plt.show()
```

The problem is, the hours are showing up as float values: ie 8.0, 9.0 etc, but I wanted it to show in 24hr time and to have a range of hours (eg from 0600 to midnight). I tried following a few other examples on here but could not get them to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why month is displaying as a float, but here's a way to show military time:

```
df['military_time'] = (df.time.dt.hour*100).map("{:04}".format)

                 time military_time
0 2015-04-19 06:00:00          0600
1 2015-04-19 19:30:00          1900
2 2015-04-19 21:00:00          2100
3 2015-04-19 21:00:00          2100
4 2015-04-19 00:00:00          0000
```